# Void elements from executing functions of the parent in angular

Tags: angular, nested, click

I have a div which contains a function with (click). The problem is that the div's that are nested (which have their own (click)) are also executing the function of the father.

I tried with the $ event.stopPropagation () but it does not work

```
  <div (click)="addThing()">
    <app-child 
      (click)="addOtherThing()">
    </app-child>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: `$event.stopPropagation()` should work. Please post your code so we can see what's actually happening.

Comment: @ConnorsFan you were right, I did not know how to use the stop.propagation () correctly. It worked. THANKS

Comment: You are welcome. I had removed my comment after your edit.